# Turning Incomplete Beta Integral to Complete Beta Integral

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals, special-functions, beta-function

On page four, equation (11) of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0811.0678v1.pdf) it is stated that when $0<\alpha<1$ the integral $$\int_0^{1/2} z^{-\alpha} (1-z)^{-2-\alpha} \;dz$$ can be "reduced to integrals for the complete beta function by elementary substitutions."

I have seen such types of substitutions say of the kind $t=(az-b)/(cz-d)$, but I cannot get those to work because the limits of integration constraint those substitutions. I assume this is why we need multiple Beta integrals but I cannot see how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My first thought is $w=1-z$ and $dw=-dz$. $\qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, assuming $\alpha<0$ integrate by parts to obtain
$$
\int_0^{1/2} z^{-\alpha} (1-z)^{-2-\alpha} \;dz=\frac{z^{-\alpha} (1-z)^{-1-\alpha}}{1+\alpha}\Big{|}_{0}^{1/2}+\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\int_0^{1/2} z^{-1-\alpha} (1-z)^{-1-\alpha} \;dz\\
=\frac{2^{1+2\alpha}}{1+\alpha}+\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}\ I.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{1/2} z^{-1-\alpha} (1-z)^{-1-\alpha} \;dz\\
&=\int_0^{1/2}  (z(1-z))^{-1-\alpha} \;dz.
\end{align}

First approach:
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{1/2}  \left(\frac{1}{4}-\left(\frac{1}{2}-z\right)^2\right)^{-1-\alpha}\;dz\\
&=\int_0^{1/2}  \left(\frac{1}{4}-t^2\right)^{-1-\alpha}\;dt\\
&=2^{1+2\alpha}\int_0^{1}  \left(1-t^2\right)^{-1-\alpha}\;dt\\
&=2^{2\alpha}\int_0^{1}  \left(1-t\right)^{-1-\alpha}t^{-1/2}\;dt\\&=2^{2\alpha}B(-\alpha,1/2).
\end{align}
This is the same as making the substitution $1-2z=\sqrt{t}$.

Second approach:
\begin{align}
I&=\int_0^{1/2}  (z(1-z))^{-1-\alpha} \;dz\\&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^{1/2}  (z(1-z))^{-1-\alpha} \;dz+\int_{1/2}^1  (z(1-z))^{-1-\alpha} \;dz\right)\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{1}  (z(1-z))^{-1-\alpha} \;dz=\frac{1}{2}B(-\alpha,-\alpha).
\end{align}

Note that the initial integral converges for $\alpha<1$. So, once it has been calculated for $\alpha<0$ it can be analytically continued to $\alpha<1$. As a result we get

> \begin{align}
> \int_0^{1/2} z^{-\alpha} (1-z)^{-2-\alpha} \;dz&=\frac{2^{1+2\alpha}}{1+\alpha}+\frac{\alpha}{1+\alpha}2^{2\alpha}B(-\alpha,1/2)\\
> &=\frac{2^{1+2\alpha}}{1+\alpha}+\frac{\alpha}{2(1+\alpha)}B(-\alpha,-\alpha),\quad \alpha<1.
> \end{align}

Comment: But does this explain how to reduce it to a complete Beta function by elementary substitutions?

Comment: Yes, $1-2z=\sqrt{t}$.

Comment: Integrals of this type and generalizations are considered in the artice "Two Remarkable Identities, Called Twos, for Inverses to Some Abelian Integrals" by Peter Lindqvist; Jaak Peetre, The American Mathematical Monthly, Vol. 108, No. 5. (May, 2001), pp. 403-410.

Comment: I tried integration by parts. From the paper, the integral evaluates to $2^{1+2\alpha}/(\alpha+1)+\alpha\Gamma(-\alpha)^2/(2(\alpha+1)\Gamma(-2\alpha)).$ The fraction term brings to mind the familiar identity with the Gama function, however, I was under the impression that the Beta function is only defined for positive values (?). Also, the first application of integration by parts yields a singularity when $\alpha>0$, circumvented by Nemo by taking $\alpha<0$. To get a integral on $[0,1]$ I  included $\pm\int_{1/2}^1" " dz$. Still, there must be some clever cancellation that I am not seeing.

Comment: @strawberryBeef , the integral converges for $\alpha<1$, so one can analytically continue it to $0<\alpha<1$ once it is calculated for $\alpha<0$.

Comment: Hmm, Thanks. I think I follow. To clarify, you consider the integral as a complex function with $\alpha$ a complex number, and extend it to the half plane $Re(\alpha)<1$. Or is there an easier way to think about it?

Comment: @strawberryBeef , yes, I consider the integral as a complex function with $\alpha$ a complex number. In my opinion this is the easiest way.