# Trying to Find Closed Form for Beta Integral

Tags: real-analysis, beta-function

$$
\mbox{Consider}\quad\int_{0}^{1/2}
v^{-t}\,\left(\, 1 - v\, \right)^{-\,\left(\, t + 1\, \right)}
\,\,\,\mathrm{d}v
$$
I have verified numerically that the integral converges for $t < 1$, but I can't get a *closed form*. Is there a way to write this in terms of the *Beta function* ?.

Comment: It's an incomplete Beta function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function

Comment: This is duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1904504/turning-incomplete-beta-integral-to-complete-beta-integral/1904608#1904608 the substitution $v=\frac{1-\sqrt{x}}{2}$ turns it into a sum of 2 complete beta integrals.

Answer (score 1):

You could write it in terms of a hypergeometric function:

$$-{\frac {{2}^{-1+t}{\mbox{$_2$F$_1$}(t+1,-t+1;\,2-t;\,1/2)}}{-1+t}}$$